# R: Problems with connecting to Hive2 via RJDBC

Tags: r, jdbc

Here's what I did:

Step one, got most recent set of JDBC drivers from Cloudera.

Step two, R Code:

```
require(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "com.cloudera.hive.jdbc41.HS2Driver",
            classPath = "C:/Rtools/JDBC_Hive/HiveJDBC41.jar")
# Stored Jars with RTools
for(l in list.files("C:/Rtools/JDBC_Hive", "jar$")){
  .jaddClassPath(paste0("C:/Rtools/JDBC_Hive/",l))
}
con <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://host:port/default;AuthMech=3;UID=login;PWD=password")
# Obviously host, port, log, pass has been substituted
```

Returns:

```
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera][HiveJDBCDriver](500151) Error setting/closing session: Open Session Error.
```

Looking around the web for similar error didn't yield obvious reasons/solutions.

Also, it's worth to mention that there are absolutely no problems with connecting to db with specialized tools like DBeaver.

Possible issues: set of Cloudera JDBC drivers are not sufficient out of the box. Maybe there is required additional configuration?

On first run, along with 500151 exception, there is also:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Error does not persist through subsequent attempts to connect.

Update:

Apparently connection/authentication works just fine but somehow driver also automatically passes weird command "set -v" which is supposed to test hive for ability to understand various SQL commands. This is where process terminates with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Used different set of jars:
https://github.com/timveil/hive-jdbc-uber-jar